# Remove specific legend items from WPF Charting Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, wpftoolkit

I'd like to remove specific items from a legend in WPF Charting Toolkit. What I've tried so far is creating a null legend item style as follows:

> ```
> <UserControl.Resources>
>     <Style x:Key="NullLegendItem" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LegendItem" >
>         <Setter Property="Template">
>             <Setter.Value>
>                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LegendItem" />
>             </Setter.Value>
>         </Setter>
>     </Style>
> </UserControl.Resources>
> ```

and then when I create the series I do:

> LegendItemStyle = (Style)this.Resources["NullLegendItem"]

This results in the following:

[image: legend]

What I'm after is the same with the empty rows removed.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No unfortunately not.